# Automating Jekyll/Github Pages builds based on time

Tags: ruby, build, automation, jekyll, github-pages

I am working on a project where I list only posts with current date(today).
It would be great to have Github(or some other tool) rebuild the site every day at midnight 00:00.

Can anyone please tell me how this can be done via Github or any other tools? Travis CI maybe? Any tutorials or examples would be much appreciated as i am very new to this.

Comment: There is https://jekyllontime.top/, which is meant to solve this problem. Disclaimer: I am the owner + it is in a very early stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a master **branch** and a **gh-pages** branch in a Github repo to use [Github pages](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-github-pages/),

Then create a [Travis Cron Job](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/cron-jobs/#Adding-Cron-Jobs) to execute the [deployment script](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/script/) on a daily basis.(as suggested by @Gorille) so it

- takes the content of the master branch and generate the site with `jekyll build` command
- push the generated site to the **gh-pages** branch.

Comment: This works, need to figure a couple of things out with travis built and deploy but overall seems to work fine. Thank you!

Comment: I am using something similar, without the cronjobs, just launching a deploy script everytime I  commit to github, it should be straightforward to do it https://github.com/marcanuy/simpleit.rocks/blob/master/deploy.sh

Answer (score -1):

You may use travis cron job :
https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/cron-jobs/

This way you can rebuild your site daily. Please beware that you cannot precisely control the hour.
I of course assume that you know how to build the site.