# How to use Travis CI to rebuild a Jekyll website every day?

Tags: jekyll, travis-ci, github-pages

I have a Jekyll based website hosted on Github pages and I would like to rebuild files every day automatically. I searched online and I found it could be done with Travis CI.

From my understanding, I would have to create a script which would then push an empty commit to github every day.

I never used CI service before so I would really appreciate if someone could explain how to do it, how to write a script, step by step.

Comment: Requests for "step by step" anything are probably too broad for here. It's a lot of work to ask a volunteer to produce, since a book could be written on the topic (and many books have been written on the topic). Have you done any research on this yourself? Maybe Travis has an API you can use to trigger a rebuild?

Comment: For example, 20 seconds of search-engine searching got me [this result](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=regular+travis+build), and the first result on dzone.com looks very good.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automating Jekyll/Github Pages builds based on time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42335256/automating-jekyll-github-pages-builds-based-on-time)

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain. I have been searching this too and I think it is way to complex to do this with Travis CI. It is possible, but it is a nightmare to setup. The process is (insufficiently) described here: [Automating Jekyll/Github Pages builds based on time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42335256/automating-jekyll-github-pages-builds-based-on-time), justifying this question.

The reason that this is overly complex is that Travis CI is not meant for this job and is basically overkill. It would be really cool if Forestry.io or CloudCannon (or any other hosted Jekyll service) would implement this, so it would become just flipping a switch.

It is funny to see that this question of the OP follows this one: [Count days in Jekyll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45712662/count-days-in-jekyll). You get the impression that the OP thinks that daily builds are the solution for the 'counting days problem'. I think that the solution to that problem is Javascript. However, daily builds of a Jekyll site would enable other basic website functions, like 'post scheduling', which cannot be solved/is much harder to solve by Javascript.